# The channelMax limit is reached

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Dependencies:

spring-boot-starter-amqp:3.1.1

I am currently using AsyncRabbitTemplate and it keeps opening a new channel. The problem is that there are more channels being created and the idle channels are not closed immediately. What would be the best way to deal with it?

```
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-10-26 06:16:52.826 WARN  [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#5-4] [/] o.s.a.r.l.DirectReplyToMessageListenerContainer - basicConsume failed, scheduling consumer for queue amq.rabbitmq.reply-to for restart
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpResourceNotAvailableException: The channelMax limit is reached. Try later.
```

This is my RabbitMQ config. I am not sure if this would be the correct config for it. I am using Spring Boot btw

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {


    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.initial-interval}")
    private int retryInitialInterval;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts}")
    private int retryMaxAttempts;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.multiplier}")
    private double retryMultiplier;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-interval}")
    private int retryMaxInterval;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-consumers}")
    private int maxConsumers;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.concurrent-consumers}")
    private int concurrentConsumers;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.rabbitmq.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory(){
        final CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setHost(host);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;

    }


    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AsyncRabbitTemplate asyncRabbitTemplate(RabbitTemplate customRabbitTemplate ) {
        return new AsyncRabbitTemplate(customRabbitTemplate);
    }
    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate customRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(customConnectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(final ConnectionFactory customConnectionFactory) {


        final SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(customConnectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumers);
        factory.setAdviceChain(messageRetryInterceptor());
        return factory;
    }


    @Bean
    public RetryOperationsInterceptor messageRetryInterceptor(){
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.StatelessRetryInterceptorBuilder
                .stateless()
                .maxAttempts(retryMaxAttempts)
//                .backOffOptions(
//                        retryInitialInterval,
//                        retryMultiplier,
//                        retryMaxInterval
//                )
                .recoverer(new RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer())
                .build();
    }


}
```